# Identify the rock soundtrack on this Runscape video?

Tags: identify-this-song, rock, soundtrack

This [Runscape video](https://youtu.be/OZgUmzp5vtE?t=248) features a rock song as soundtrack.

I have tried to ask the owner, and looking in the comment section but found no answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it by the way, its called Demilitarized Zone by Ethan Meixsell: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6P44UkFlTc8